# Creating a UserForm with Variable Number of Inputs

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am looking to create a new UserForm to make it easier for the evaluation team here. Essentially, they must evaluate proposals from a number of firms (anywhere from 2 to 12 or so) against certain factors by ranking the firms in order or preference/suitability. We've had complaints about user errors and confusion when they're just putting the numbers straight onto the spreadsheet itself, so it's been left to me to clean it up and make it more "user-friendly" for them.

I have the set-up part done, where users are asked to input the number of firms to be evaluated, the type of evaluation to carry out (this changes the metrics, but there are always 6 of them), and the names of the firms. The firm names are all put into a Named Range ("evalFirms") on a hidden sheet.

What I'd like is for a new UserForm to then be set up with two columns, the left hand being populated by TextBoxes with the evalFirms the user entered at set up and the right hand being an input to Rank the firms such that each rank is unique (i.e. not having two firms ranking 1st).

```
Evaluation Metric 1

Firm A   |   2
Firm B   |   1
  :      |   :
Firm n   |   n
```

These ranks will then be passed to a hidden sheet where the relevant calculations are done. That part is also all set up and ready to go, it is just this middle part that's given me headaches. The text box at the top should cycle through each of the 6 evaluation metrics (also a dynamic named range called "evalMetrics") until all firms have been fully evaluated.

I'm not super experienced with UserForms, so I'm having trouble with the varying amount of inputs. I can set up a static form, but rather than set up 12 different forms and have each called depending on the number of firms being evaluated, I'd prefer to have a single dynamic form.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You only need one form with space for 12 firms - just hide or disable the controls for the unused slots

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't considered that. 12 is fairly typical for a high volume proposal, I've seen as many as 30 on occasion. I hadn't thought about setting up a larger form and hiding controls though, so thanks for that. I'll look into it. Like I said, I'm not super experienced with UserForms.

Comment: This is a very, very broad subject, I could write an entire chapter of a book to cover everything about this... and this site won't let me post an answer with more than a mere 30K characters... can you narrow the scope down a bit, to a more *specific* problem? Do you have any code written at al?

Comment: Ah well, no worries. If it's too difficult, I'll be able to bodge out something workable along the lines of Tim's idea. Might not look pretty, but I reckon it'll work in most cases. The headache is all my own fault for speaking up with a "bright idea" without thinking in front of mgmt anyways! Thanks all the same.

Comment: If you have trouble making this work on a UserForm, you might consider implementing it on a worksheet - maybe more configured/locked down than your current one.

Comment: I'd actually been working on a new version of the workbook to make it easier in any case, but had made the mistake of offhandedly saying to a manager than a UserForm might be am more elegant solution and ever since then he's been pushing hard for that so I'm going to have to deliver something workable and then make the case that the spreadsheet is better! Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: I built a dynamic userform based on the [example code on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/205263/106798) by @Tinman and it worked very well. I think this type of form, where you can add as many rows as needed, would be an easy to use front end for your users.